# "My Documents" as the first class citizen in "Documents" in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, start-menu, my-documents

In windows 7, you can have a "Document" as a menu on the "Start Menu".

However, it lead to sub-items "My Documents" and "Public Documents".

As well as only me is using my notebook, "Public Documents" is useless and waste me for a click to the "My Documents".

So, my question is -- how do I hack the registry(without hacking DLLs) to make **the contents in "My Documents" as the first class citizen in the start menu?**

PS. after read this, I've removed the "Public Documents" from the library.
But still, it takes me one more click

Answer (score 1):

Since you are the only user of your laptop you can customize the start menu to display the Documents as a link, not as a menu.
(Right click on task bar, select Properties, click the Start Menu tab -> Customize and scroll down to Documents and select the Display as link radio button).

This will take you directly to your documents

Answer (score 1):

One option: bring up the Start menu, and right click on the Documents item. Select Properties. Now you can add/delete whatever folders you want to appear here.  I removed Public, and added some often used folders.  E.g., I have a folder My Documents\Projects that I use a lot, so I added Projects to the list.  You could add movies, photos, music folders here too.